# ROS Hydro Source code

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROSian's....

Is there any way to download the source code for ROS Hydro or any other distribution of ROS. I have referred the sites mentioned below for obtaining the ROS source code, but I can't download them. I want them as a whole source code in a single package.

wiki.ros.org/Source%20code

code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/

I want the source codes in order to cross-compile the ROS for ARM processors.

Please anybody help me to get out of this juggle.....

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153946/ros-hydro-source-code/) by [sonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/13381/sonny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Goto: http://wiki.ros.org/

Then click on: `Install` - Install ROS on your machine

Then click on: `Ubuntu Source installation`

This wiki page describes how a set of ROS packages in Hydro can be compiled from source and therefore the first part contains the instructions how to download the source code for that.

Instead of the last link you could also click on `UbuntuARM` which will give you ARM specific instruction.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/13381/sonny/) on 2014-04-17**:
Thanks Dirk Thomas for this help, finally I am able to download the source code what I needed.

Can you tell me is there any procedure to cross-compile the ROS for ARM processor, so that i can run ROS codes on ARM boards.

Thanks...

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2014-04-17**:
You might find some insight in the wiki page about installing Groovy from source on a RaspberryPi: http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source